# How to restrict any Listview to be chosen any particular color in c#?

Tags: c#

```
if (listView1.BackColor  == Color.Blue)
{
    MessageBox.Show("This is not valid color. Please choose another ");    
}
```

Actually i don't want that any one choose the blues color .

when i apply the above code , it is restricting me to choose any other color. Every time showing me the message in message box. Please suggest solution

Comment: You have posted asimple if statement, how is that going to help us?

Comment: Is it that you want to check the BackColor of Selected item and you are instead checking the BackColor of the ListView itself?

Comment: You cannot directly compare arbitrary colors with color values from the `Color` class, because the latter includes the name while the former will not. See marked duplicate for details. I'll also note that your logic seems misplaced; checking the color _after_ it's been assigned seems too late...you probably should prevent that selection at some earlier stage (without a good [mcve] it's impossible to offer anything more specific than that).